# curl page not working

Tags: php, curl

I have this code to load external pages on my website:

```
<?php 
function curl($url){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
  }


  $url = 'http://rooster.csvincentvangogh.nl:8081';
  $contents = curl($url);
  echo $contents;
?>
```

It works for most sites, but not the one I need: `http://rooster.csvincentvangogh.nl:8081`. Is this because of the :8081? It needs to be there though, otherwise the site doesn't work... How could I fix this? Is there an alternative way, in stead of curl?

I tested it on http://portquiz.net. Ports such as 80 and 8080 work, but e.g. 8888 and 8081 not. 
http://rooster.csvincentvangogh.nl:8080 works too, but that has different directories and not the pages I need. I really do need the pages on :8081...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no error or something, just a blank screen. The page itself does work of course.

Comment: You can also telnet in and GET /

Comment: Try piping into telnet:
(echo -e "GET /<subpage>\nexit\n") | telnet <domain/subdoman> 80
This should work.

Comment: I don't understand how?.. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /home/u961329959/public_html/beta/proxy.php on line 12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i GUESS its because its detecting the 404 error and thus want to return an "error" (bool(false)?) to warn you, so it discards the body and ignores CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFERS. anyway, use this.

```
function curl($url,&$body){
            $ch = curl_init();
            $tmpfile=tmpfile();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FILE,$tmpfile);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
            $ret = curl_exec($ch);
            $body=file_get_contents ( stream_get_meta_data ($tmpfile) ['uri'] );
            curl_close($ch);
            fclose($tmpfile);
            return $ret;
  }
```

also consider CURLOPT_STDERR with CURLOPT_VERBOSE to get detailed information about what curl is thinking ^^ (often very useful debug info when "it doesn't work")

Comment: So when I call the function, do I just do curl($url)?
When I do that, all I get is still blank screen..
And no, it's not because of the 404 error, because on sites like portquiz.net:8081 it doesn't work either...

Comment: @robinvdnoord no, you call it like this: `$body='';$ret=curl('http://rooster.csvincentvangogh.nl:8081',$body);var_dump($ret,$body);` also i fixed 2x syntax errors, sorry, try the new code

Comment: Thanks, but it still only gives a white screen.. I think my server or cloudflare is blocking it or something..

UPDATE it displayed this: `bool(false) string(0) ""`

Comment: @robinvdnoord are you on php7 or php5?

Comment: EDIT: ignore the code in paste 413939, try THIS code, what does it say? http://paste.debian.net/413940/

Comment: Just keeps loading forever

Comment: did you set 0 to CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT or something? x.x

Comment: Same story. Thanks for all the help, but I think I should just give up and try another way..

Comment: run it in shell `/usr/bin/php test.php`, not behind a caching service

Comment: On my local machine in terminal it seems to work, and your original code too.

Comment: on my server I'm using php 7. I can downgrade if that's needed?

Comment: use php7, that's the best version now :p then try this code http://paste.debian.net/413946/

Comment: I get this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: curl_exec failed. errno: 28 error: 'Connection timed out after 4001 milliseconds' in /home/u961329959/public_html/beta/proxy.php:196 Stack trace: #0 /home/u961329959/public_html/beta/proxy.php(6): hhb_curl->exec('http://rooster....') #1 {main} thrown in /home/u961329959/public_html/beta/proxy.php on line 196 `

Comment: I have curl 7.47.1 if that's important

Comment: no, that shows the issue, http://rooster.csvincentvangogh.nl:8081 does not accept connections from your server's IP ^^

Comment: Ah, I see.. I found a proxy that works though (http://auto-aufladen.de/browse.php?u=http://rooster.csvincentvangogh.nl:8081/ gives a 404 error but the subdirectories work) so I think I'll just link to that, even though that looks kinda stupid :) Thanks for the effort!

Comment: I made an iframe with that page on a non-https page and now it looks a bit nicer :) Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting the port:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8081);
```

So you can remove :8081 from your URL.
Note: make sure you have the curl module installed

Comment: function_exists('curl_version'); returns 1, so I think it is installed. I added the code but still nothing shows up...

Comment: When I try e.g. http://portquiz.net without CURLOPT_PORT it works, but when I add CURLOPT_PORT 8081 it does not work anymore...
Ports 80 and 8080 on portquiz do work though...

Comment: for HTTP / HTTPS (and probably others), curl is smart enough to set CURLOPT_PORT according to :X automatically, so that's not it. its probably because curl detect 404 as error.

Comment: It's not because of the 404 error, because portquiz.net:8081 does not work either... @hanshenrik